# Chat de SOes redirecciona a Area51

Tags: soporte

Al intentar ir al chat de SOes, mi navegador se redirecciona al sitio de [Area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/):

¿Existe alguna situación con los servidores de chat?

Publico acá ya que no puedo hacerlo en el chat por obvias razones.

Comment: Que extraño ¿te sigue pasando?, no noto nada raro

Comment: No, solo duro un espacio de tiempo en el momento en que hice este reporte, pero no hubo respuesta de los mod del sitio por que ocurrio, etc...